# Running different docker containers on same host/different port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, networking

I have an app composed of multiple rails projects, I am trying to dockerize them, each app starts on a different rails port :

- main app: 1665
- admin: 3002
- website: 3000
- ...

This is my docker-compose.yml file :

```
version: '2'
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    container_name: acme_db
    hostname: db.myapp.dev
    hostname: db.ach
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - myapp_pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    environment:
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=db.myapp.dev
    networks:
      - generic

  myapp:
    image: acme/myapp
    container_name: acme_myapp
    hostname: app.myapp.dev
    command: rails s -p 1665 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - ./myapp:/usr/src/app
      - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/tmp/ssh_auth_sock
    ports:
      - "1665:1665"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh_auth_sock
      - RAILS_ENV=development
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=myapp.dev
    networks:
      - generic

  admin:
    image: acme/admin
    container_name: acme_admin
    hostname: admin2.myapp.dev
    command: rails s -p 3002 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - ./admin2:/usr/src/app
      - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/tmp/ssh_auth_sock
    ports:
      - "3002:3002"
    depends_on:
      - myapp
    environment:
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh_auth_sock
      - RAILS_ENV=development
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=admin2.myapp.dev
    networks:
      - generic

  website:
    image: acme/website
    container_name: acme_website
    hostname: web.myapp.dev
    command: rails s -p 3001 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - ./website:/usr/src/app
      - $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/tmp/ssh_auth_sock
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    environment:
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh_auth_sock
      - RAILS_ENV=development
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=myapp.dev
    networks:
      - generic

volumes:
  myapp_pgdata:
    external: true

networks:
  generic:
    external: true
```

Running each app works fine, but I have a problem when applications need to communicate between them, for instance the website need to forward an http request to the main app, and when it does, it tries to resolve this uri: `http://app.myapp.dev:1665/register` and, the resolved ip is 127.0.0.1 instead of the `myapp` docker container ip.

How can I manage this situation ? Should I use completely different hostnames for each container ? Ideally I would like to avoid DNS resolution so rails tries to hit `app.myapp.dev:1665` instead of resolving `app.myapp.dev` and then resolving `127.0.0.1:1665`

btw, I am using `jwilder/nginx-proxy` to resolve containers hostnames from my laptop.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: So this hit is through the browser or inside the app code itself? And why don't you use `app:1665` for the connection?

Comment: the hit is through the Rails code, ideally I would like to keep the apps in a "project scope", hence the "app1.project.dev, app2.project.dev" structure, but even by using the names as you suggested (`app.1665`), the problem is the same, apparently it works best when adding network aliases, but network aliases doesn't works when using sub-sub domains (if the net alias is `app.dev`, when hitting `sub.app.dev` the resolution goes again to 127.0.0.1)

Comment: See the thing that is that your app when it is run in compose each service can reach other using names `db`, `myapp`, `admin`, `website`. So you should not be concerned about they are being reached externally, as long as these calls are server to server. Also I am not sure why you have used a external `generic` network?

Answer (score 0):

Your setup allows your containers to resolve each other by their names through the 'network' set up by docker-compose.

So `website` should be able to hit the main app through `http://myapp:1665/register`